# Is there a way to globally set my json decoding to handle upper and lower case, camel case from snake_case?

Tags: scala, circe

My JSON looks like:

```
created_at
```

While my case classes have properties like

```
createdAt
```

Is there a way to globally set this during my encoding/decoding?  I don't want to have to customize my decoder/encoder for each property.

I tried getting circe-generic-extras and did this:

implicit val customConfig: Configuration          = Configuration.default.withSnakeCaseMemberNames

But when I run my unit tests, I still get the error:

```
Actual:   Left(DecodingFailure(Attempt to decode value on failed cursor, List(DownField(createdAt))))
```

I have so many properties in my case classes that I don't want to write this out manually to fix this, looking for a auto/lazy way :)

```
import io.circe._
import io.circe.generic.semiauto._
import io.circe.generic.extras.Configuration

case class MyComponent(
  createdAt: String
)

object MyComponent {
implicit val customConfig: Configuration          = Configuration.default.withSnakeCaseMemberNames
  implicit val componentDecoder: Decoder[MyComponent] = deriveDecoder[MyComponent]
  implicit val componentEncoder: Encoder[MyComponent] = deriveEncoder[MyComponent]
}
```

And my spec2 test:

```
  val decodedComponent = parser.decode[MyComponent](jsonString)
  decodedComponent must_=== Right(expected)
```

Comment: The easiest way is probably to define the implicit in a high-level package object, so that it is automatically available everywhere in your code. (I wouldn't recommend this or typically do it myself, though.)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I updated my question with the code

Comment: @Blankman you need to use `deriveConfiguredDecoder` that comes from `circe.generic.extras.semiauto`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez that worked!

Comment: @Blankman BTW, if you want an **Encoder** and a **Decoder** you can juts derive a **Codec**. Also, you may want to put that configuration in a trait that each companion object inherits so you can save a bit of boilerplate.